# problem with xetex after updating to ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS

Tags: xetex, errors, ubuntu, dvipdfmx, texlive2022

Xetex doesn't work if I try to use tex->pdf. I suppose the problem comes from compatiblity issues. I have no idea what "L3 programming layer" is.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/gabrielle/.cache/gummi/gummi_ZVEKT1
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def:80: Argum
ent of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
```

Surprinsingly, it works if I use tex->dvi->pdf instead. I noticed it's not the same version of l3backend which is in the log file : l3backend-dvips.def. Could I have a problem with dvipdf ?

Compilation with tex->dvi->ps->pdf also works but the document is upside down...

I used a very simple example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 TEST
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please also show an example of what exactly are you trying to compile using xelatex? Does a standard `hello world` doc work? (`\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello world\end{document}`)

Comment: The example works perfectly fine with TeX Live 2022. How did you install your TeX distribution? If by any chance you tried to used the one packaged by Ubuntu, you'll easily find many posts here explaining why it isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Miyase if you look at the OPs error sample that seems to indeed be the case. Though does not quite explain why xelatex is broken in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Yes, I use the tex live distribution packged by ubuntu 22.04.1. I'm sorry to see I shouldn't. It was working with th ubuntu 20.04 version. What tex live 2022 version should I use and how can I find it ?

Comment: @miyase I can't fin any posts explaining, where should I look ?

Comment: there is perhaps something wrong with the extractbb-call but your versions are a bit older than mine and I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using LuaTeX instead and the tex->pdf compilation is working.

I think it-s related to ghoscript and options that should be used during the compilation as shown in [texlive guide in french](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-fr/texlive-fr.html#x1-9600010.2)
xetex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" foo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Since this is not an answer to the question, it would be better to edit your question and add this information.